# POSTMAN Assertion with IF ELSE statement not working

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I need to test the response code and if it is true do next api call.I am using below code to achieve the desired functionality. Let me know what am i doing wrong.

```
pm.test("response is valid", function(){
if(pm.response.code === 201){
    postman.setNextRequest("Auto-Deploy Manager Node 2");
} 
else {
    setTimeout(function(){}, 10000);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using this in the Collection Runner?

Comment: yep, this is in collection runner

Comment: What's not working? What is it doing now? What's the timeout for? What are you asserting? You might as well not have that wrapped in a test.